# Are @imagecreatefromjpeg and imagejpeg() effective for preventing users from uploading images with malicious php code within them?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

Here is the code in `upload_processor.php`:

```
include_once 'functions.php';

$name = $_FILES['upload-image']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['upload-image']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['upload-image']['size'];
$temp = $_FILES['upload-image']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['upload-image']['error'];

img_processor($temp, $error, $size)
```

And here is `functions.php`:

```
function img_processor($img_temp, $img_error, $img_size){
    if($img_error===0){
        if($img_size < 4194304){
            if( $proc_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($img_temp) ){
                imagejpeg($proc_img,'../uploaded/something.jpeg');
            } elseif( $proc_img = @imagecreatefrompng($img_temp) ){
                imagepng($proc_img,'../uploaded/something.png');
            } elseif( $proc_img = @imagecreatefromgif($img_temp) ){
                imagegif($proc_img,'../uploaded/something.gif');
            } else {
                echo("Only JPEGs, PNGs, and GIFs are allowed");
            }

            if(isset($proc_img)){
                echo("upload complete");                
            }

        } else {
            echo("Your file was too big. Only images that are 4MB or less are allowed");
        }
    } else {
        echo('Error uploading file! Code '.$img_error);
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to recreate the image, then rename it so that no one can upload something like `malicious_code.php.jpg`.

What are the holes in this code? Are there better ways to protect my site from PHP-injected images?

Comment: You can craft images that contain PHP code that can withstand the `imagecreatefrom*` and `image*` functions. There is a quite [famous example of an PNG file containing PHP code in the IDAT chunks that withstands resizing](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2012/06/encoding-web-shells-in-png-idat-chunks/).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `imagegreatefrom*` will return false if there's an error so the `@` operator isn't really doing much in this situation.
2. Instead of calling `imagecreatefrom*`, you can check to see if the input file is valid using `exif_imagetype` and then call an appropriate handler.  I am not sure if there are security implications (although intuitively it sounds like there could be security problems with the above code), but the performance should improve, as you're not having to create an image resource every time a truth test fails.

   ```
   $handlers = array(
       IMAGETYPE_GIF => 'imagecreatefromgif',
       IMAGETYPE_JPEG => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
       IMAGETYPE_PNG => 'imagecreatefrompng'
   );
   $type = exif_imagetype($img_temp);

   if(array_key_exists($type,$handlers)){
          $proc_img = call_user_func_array($handlers[$type],array($img_temp));
   } else {
       // do error logic here
   }
   ```

The other added benefit is that you can add handlers without having to make a giant if statement. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php for more info.